# as.numeric(Sys.time()) as a condition in a loop

Tags: r, time, numeric

I am trying to a create a data frame, but I want to create each input with a time condition:

```
i=1
df=as.data.frame(matrix(c(NA), ncol =1))
while (i <= 1000){if (as.numeric(Sys.time())%%2 == 0){df[i,] <- [i]
    df$timestamp <- Sys.time()
    print(i)
    i=1+i
  }
}
```

But

```
as.numeric(Sys.time())%%2 == 0
```

is false all the time.

Comment: you should use `as.integer` rather than `as.numeric`

Comment: One reason the `%% 2 == 0` is false is related to [R FAQ 7.31](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_82.html).

Comment: Thanks, with that modification all the inputs are created at the same time. What I all looking for is that each input is created every other second.